# Usage of FilterOutputStream

Tags: java, stream, output, outputstream

What is practical usage of `FilterOutputStream` in Java? 
From javadocs:

> This class is the superclass of all classes that filter output streams. These streams sit on top of an already existing output stream (the underlying output stream) which it uses as its basic sink of data, but possibly transforming the data along the way or providing additional functionality.

For me it seems to have same methods as `OutputStream` (maybe it overrides them for some reason?). What kind of data "transformation" does it offer and when can one use it in own Java application?

Comment: @Val getting page not found for the URL in your comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Joshua Bloch in *Effective Java Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance* explains why *inheritance is not always the best tool for the job.* It is often more efficient to use Decorator pattern. FilterOutputStream and FilterInputStream are the base for implementing this pattern. For example I want to block OutputStream.close. This is what I could do

```
class NonCloseableOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    public NonCloseableOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

Now my class can accept any subclass of OutputStream and make it non-closeable.

Comment: Please BEWARE at least in Android SDK because `FilterOutputStream.write(byte[],int,int)` implemenation doesn't call the delegate `write(byte[], int, int)` but does a loop for each byte calling `write(byte)` for each one. If you are using it over a FileOutputStream you'll have a bad time (and probably if not, you'll have a not-very-nice time anyway).

Answer (score 3):

> The class FilterOutputStream itself simply overrides all methods of OutputStream with versions that pass all requests to the underlying output stream.

So as you suspected, it doesn't do much besides overrides the methods with a somewhat more useful implementation.

These classes are from Java 1.0, so they may not be designed in the best possible way. However, extending a `FilterStream` will still work just fine, in case you need to create your own (although there are ready-made filter streams (like `CheckedInputStream`, `DigestInputStream` or `CipherInputStream`) for plenty of things).

Answer (score 1):

`CheckedInputStream` looked useful to me. It calculates a checksum based on data passed through it. I could see myself using that.

Another example is the `DeflateOutputStream` which handles compressing data formatted correctly, automatically.

I think you understand exactly what it's used for. Subclasses just manipulate data before forwarding it on to the underlying stream.

Answer (score 1):

It has the same methods as `OutputStream`, since it extends `OutputStream`. In fact, that is  a very useful feature: you can supply a `FilterOutputStream` anywhere an `OutputStream` is expected.

By default, a `FilterOutputStream` does not offer you any added functionality. As its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) states:

> Subclasses of `FilterOutputStream` may further override some of these methods

For example, you could extend `FilterOutputStream` and override the `write(int b)` method in a way that it writes any byte you supply to it, except `13` or `10`. That way, you would have an outputstream that never contains newlines. It may not be of any use, but its just an example.